# Selenium error namely 'selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I received this error while trying to automate sending message in whatsapp. here is the source code.

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/HP/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)
target = 'Name of friend or group'
string = "Hello!! sent using selenium.."
x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target + ')]'
group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, x_arg)))
group_title.click()
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="input"][@dir="auto"][@data-tab="1"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))
for i in range(100):
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please add the complete exception stack trace. This helps us in tracing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the element you are trying to interact with is not in the main flow of your current farm
you should consider changing the frame:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(input_box)
```

and when done

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: the interaction here is send_keys so do switch before that

Answer (score 0):

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable This error means, that when you tried to click on an element it was uninteractable. So, for example if you have a dropped list of buttons first you should open this list and then click on the button. May be when you do this code group_title.click() your group_title uninteractable.